# How to pass IOptions to an ASP.NET 5 middle-ware service?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have started playing around with ASP.NET 5 vNext and I am struggling passing the options from config.json into a middle-ware service that is used by my WebApi controller.

Here is a snippet with my middle-ware service:

```
public class MyService : IMyService 
{
        public MyService(IOptions<MyOptions> settings)
        {
            var o = settings.Options;
        }
}
```

Here is my WebApi controller that is using the middle-ware service:

```
public class MyController : Controller
    {
        private IMyService _myService;

        public TestController(IMyService service)
        {
            _myService = service;
        }
}
```

In Startup.cs I am reading the options:

```
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);
```

What I am struggling with is how to register an instance to IMyService so that it would be passed to the constructor of the controller (how can I get a hold of the IOptions)?

```
services.AddInstance<IMyService>(new MyService(XXXXX));
```

As suggested below I did try to use both

```
services.AddTransient<MyService>();
```

and

```
services.AddSingleton<MyService>();
```

But in both cases I am seeing the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'MyApp.Services.IMyService' while attempting to activate
>   'MyApp.Controllers.TestController'.
>   Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
>   sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't register it as an Instance.  Instead just add it as Scoped/Transient/Singleton depending on your requirements and let Dependency Injection do its magic;

```
services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions"));
services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have tried your suggestion but now I am getting an  InvalidOperationException exception when the page tries to load. I have updated the question as the text was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can to add to Startup.cs that code:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder("[path to file with configuration]");
        builder.AddJsonFile("config.json");
        var config = builder.Build();

        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<MyOptions>(config);

        //services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
        services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
    }
```

I can assure you that you can use Singleton or Transient.

If you're interested, you can find more info here https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/24.

And additionally, currently Autofac creates DI for ASP.NET 5 on 
http://alexmg.com/autofac-4-0-alpha-1-for-asp-net-5-0-beta-3/