# Passing IOptions into .Net core middleware class for json config retrieval

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, configuration, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to use strongly typed json config settings as per the [Options pattern](http://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/) in .net core. All examples so far show how easy it is to inject the strongly typed settings class into a controller but I need to use it in a middleware class (Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792245/how-to-pass-ioptions-to-an-asp-net-5-middle-ware-service) but I'm no further forward after trying it that way).

So, the setup:

**mysettings.json**

```
{
  "MySettings": {
    "Name": "Some Name from config",
    "Description": "Some Description from config"
  }
}
```

**mysettings.cs**

```
public class MySettings
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Default name";

    public string Description { get; set; } = "Default description";
}
```

**startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    // Add functionality to inject IOptions<T>
    services.AddOptions();

    // Add our Config object so it can be injected
    services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
    services.AddSingleton<IMySettingsService, MySettingsService>();
}
```

**MysettingsService.cs**

```
public class MysettingsService : IMysettingsService
{
    private MySettings mySettings { get; set; }

    public MysettingsService (MySettings _mySettings)
    {
        mySettings = _mySettings.value;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return mySettings.Name; 
    }
}
```

How do I go about instantiating **MysettingsService.cs** and injecting an `IOptions<MySettings>` into the class constructor so I can call the **GetName** method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Few points:

- Constructor is missing in the mentioned class - **MysettingsService**
- Did you register the implementation of **IMysettingsService** in **Startup** class?
- While registering the implementation, you can initialize the **MysettingsService**, like below: 
  `services.AddSingleton<IMysettingsService, MysettingsService >(i => new MysettingsService ());`

Follow these steps:

- Make sure that you have registered your JSON file - mysettings.json - in ConfigurationBuilder
- Define **MySettings**

  ```
  public class MySettings
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }

      public string Description { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Define **MySettingsService**

  ```
  public class MySettingsService : IMySettingsService
  {
      private readonly MySettings mySettings;

      public MySettingsService (IOptions<MySettings> _mySettings)
      {
          mySettings = _mySettings.Value;
      }

      public string GetName()
      {
          return mySettings.Name; 
      }
  }
  ```
- In Startup

  ```
  services.Configure<MySettings>(this.Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
  services.AddSingleton<IMySettingsService, MySettingsService >();
  ```

**EDITED -- I am including the implementation for you to follow**

I have created a sample application and it works for me; Please follow the steps below:

Few details. 
My application name is: `SettingsApp`

1. Create the settings files - `mySettings.json` - with the contents

> ```
> {
>   "MySettings": {
>     "Name": "Some Name from config",
>     "Description": "Some Description from config"
>   }
> }
> ```

2. Configure it in the `Startup`

> ```
> public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
> {
>     var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
>         .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
>         .AddJsonFile("mySettings.json", true, reloadOnChange: true)
>         .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
>         .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
>         .AddEnvironmentVariables();
>
>     if (env.IsDevelopment())
>     {
>         // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
>         builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
>     }
>     Configuration = builder.Build();
> }
> ```

See the line:

> .AddJsonFile("mySettings.json", true, reloadOnChange: true)

3. Create `MySettings` object to hold the settings

> ```
> namespace SettingsApp.Initialisations
> {
>     public class MySettings
>     {
>         public string Name { get; set; }
>
>         public string Description { get; set; }
>     }
> }
> ```

**Note:** I use the namespace `SettingsApp.Initialisations` to keep this file. You can choose any based on your application structure.

4. Create the interface `IMySettingsService`

> ```
> namespace SettingsApp.Services
> {
>     public interface IMySettingsService
>     {
>         string GetName();
>     }
> }
> ```

**Note:** I use the namespace `SettingsApp.Services` for this.

5. Implement the interface - `IMySettingsService`

> ```
> using SettingsApp.Initialisations;
> using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
>
> namespace SettingsApp.Services
> {
>     public class MySettingsService : IMySettingsService
>     {
>         private readonly MySettings mySettings;
>
>         public MySettingsService(IOptions<MySettings> _mySettings)
>         {
>             mySettings = _mySettings.Value;
>         }
>
>         public string GetName()
>         {
>             return mySettings.Name;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

6. Add the options and let the system know your implementation in `Startup.ConfigureServices` method

> ```
> // This method gets called by the run time. Use this method to add services to the container.
> public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
> {
>     // Options
>     services.AddOptions();
>     services.Configure<MySettings>(this.Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
>     services.AddSingleton<IMySettingsService, MySettingsService>();
>
>     // Add framework services.
>     services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
>
>     services.AddMvc();
> }
> ```

Note to include the required using's.

Check the code below on how this is done:

> ```
> // Options
> services.AddOptions();
> services.Configure<MySettings>(this.Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
> services.AddSingleton<IMySettingsService, MySettingsService>();
> ```

7. Use the implementation (I am using the `HomeController` for testing.)

> ```
> public class HomeController : Controller
> {
>     private IMySettingsService mySettingsService;
>
>     public HomeController(IMySettingsService settingsService)
>     {
>         mySettingsService = settingsService;
>     }
>
>     public IActionResult Index()
>     {
>         // Get the settings
>         var name = mySettingsService.GetName();
>
>         return View();
>     }
>
> ...
> ```

8. See  the results:

[image: Home controller constructor]
[image: Inside the action]

Comment: Thanks fo the help but I've completed all the steps you've mentioned. How do I go about using an instance of MySettingsservice to call the GetName method? In particular, how do I pass in a IOptions<MySettings> to satisfy the constructor?

Comment: If all above is done - along with letting the configuration know about the mysettings.json file (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html), I would be curious to know what you get as a result in the constructor of **MySettingsService**? Put a debug point there and let us know what is the injected object?

Comment: Thanks. I just realised DI would take care of MySettingsService's constructor if I just consumed its interface. Your thorough implementation helped.

Comment: this is great if i did all my work in the controller but i dont.. i need to pass configuration down to all child classes as well.. this can get kind of messy

Answer (score 2):

In newer version of .NET above binding method does not work anymore.

I have created an extension method that works:

```
    public static void AddSettings<T>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IConfiguration configuration) where T : class, new()
    {
        var settings = new T();
        configuration.Bind(typeof(T).Name, settings);
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton(settings);
    }
```

Use it like this:

```
services.AddSettings<LoggingSettings>(configuration);
```

Full example:

```
        string pathToConfigFile = "c:\\config.json";
        IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(pathToConfigFile, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

        var services = new ServiceCollection()

        services.AddSingleton(configuration);

        services.AddSettings<ConnectionSettings>(configuration);
        services.AddSettings<LoggingSettings>(configuration);
        services.AddSettings<AutoCreateSettings>(configuration);
```